# SQL Server: how do I get data from a history table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you please help me build an SQL query to retrieve data from a history table?

I'm a newbie with only a one-week coding experience. I've been trying simple SELECT statements so far but have hit a stumbling block.

My football club's database has three tables. The first one links balls to players:

```
BallDetail

| BallID | PlayerID | TeamID |
|-------------------|--------|
|      1 |       11 |     21 |
|      2 |       12 |     22 |
```

The second one lists things that happen to the balls:

```
BallEventHistory

| BallID | Event |  EventDate |
|--------|------ |------------|
|      1 |  Pass | 2012-01-01 |
|      1 | Shoot | 2012-02-01 |
|      1 |  Miss | 2012-03-01 |
|      2 |  Pass | 2012-01-01 |
|      2 | Shoot | 2012-02-01 |
```

And the third one is a history change table. After a ball changes hands, history is recorded:

```
HistoryChanges

| BallID | ColumnName | ValueOld | ValueNew |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|
|      2 |   PlayerID |       11 |       12 |
|      2 |     TeamID |       21 |       22 |
```

I'm trying to obtain a table that would list all passes and shoots Player 11 had done to all balls before the balls went to other players. Like this:

```
| PlayerID | BallID | Event | Month |
|----------|--------|-------|-------|
|       11 |      1 |  Pass |   Jan |
|       11 |      1 | Shoot |   Feb |
|       11 |      2 |  Pass |   Jan |
```

I begin so:

```
SELECT PlayerID, BallID, Event, DateName(month, EventDate)
FROM BallDetail bd INNER JOIN BallEventHistory beh ON bd.BallID = beh.BallID
WHERE PlayerID = 11 AND Event IN (Pass, Shoot) ...
```

But how to make sure that Ball 2 also gets included despite being with another player now?

Comment: No. I'm not a student. But the example has been simplified and camouflaged, and it may give you that impression.

Comment: Aren't you missing some data here?  You are keeping track of the time when the shoot, pass, etc. occur.  However, you are not keeping track of the time when the ball changes to a different player.

Comment: You are right, Ek0nomik. There's another column in HistoryChanges: ChangeDate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select PlayerID,BallID,Event,datename(month,EventDate) as Month,Count(*) as cnt from
(
Select 
Coalesce(
(Select ValueNew from #HistoryChanges where ChangeDate=(Select max(ChangeDate) from #HistoryChanges h2 where h2.BallID=h.BallID and ColumnName='PlayerID' and ChangeDate<=EventDate) and  BallID=h.BallID and ColumnName='PlayerID')
,(Select PlayerID from #BallDetail where BallID=h.BallID)
) as PlayerID,
h.BallID,h.Event,EventDate
from #BallEventHistory h
) a
Group by PlayerID, BallID, Event,datename(month,EventDate)
```

Comment: uups, sorry, didn't see the changing of the players

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.PlayerID, d.BallID, h.Event, DATENAME(mm, h.EventDate) AS Month
FROM BallDetail d JOIN BallEventHistory h ON d.BallID = h.BallID 
WHERE h.Event IN ('Pass', 'Shoot') AND d.PlayerID = 11
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.HistoryChanges c
             WHERE c.ValueOld = 11 AND c.ValueNew = d.PlayerID AND c.ColumnName = 'PlayerID' and c.ChangeDate = h.EventDate)
```